# How to make wireframe bones not semi-opaque in 2.9?

Tags: 3d-view, armature, wireframe

How can I restore the 2.79 look of wireframe bones while in Pose and Edit mode? I want these bones to actually show as wireframes, and not semi-transparent/semi-opaque.

Here is a comparison of some random bones in 2.79b and in 2.9. All views are taken in Wireframe Mode.

[image]

While I prefer the older visuals, my primary concern is that the new 'wireframe' bones obstruct the eyedropper tool. In 2.79b I can select objects through/behind a wireframe bone, but I can't select anything through the 2.9 opaque wireframe bones.

Comment: I haven't found a way to revert that behavior, but would it work for you to change the armature's Display Settings from Octahedral to either Wire or Stick?

Comment: I guess you need to suggest that to Right Click Select

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in *Object > Viewport Display > Display As Wire*.